# Rendering data in a view aspboilerplate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, aspnetboilerplate

I am wanting to learn how to simply display data in a view using aspnetboilerplate (aspnet zero) without going through a workflow of first adding the data. I already have the data I need in the database table, but just need to display it.

I understand that you have to do the following steps:

1. Create dbset
2. Create an application service
3. Create a model with the data you want returned
4. Reference the model in a controller
5. Return the data from controller to the view
6. Create the view content

I understand the process, but I am just having trouble piecing everything together. It just doesn't seem too straight forward. Could someone provide me with a simple example of what I am trying to do?

Any help would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: Official guide: [Developing Step By Step Core](https://aspnetzero.com/Documents/Developing-Step-By-Step-Core)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the data retrieved from database, you can easily write on your view. Actually this is not related with Aspnet Boilerplate. It's MVC basics. See the sample code

```cs
@using MyCompanyName.AbpZeroTemplate.Web.Areas.AppAreaName.Models.Common
@model OrganizationUnitTreeItemModel
@{
    var organizationUnits = Model.EditModel.AllOrganizationUnits.ToList();
    <ul>
        @foreach (var organizationUnit in organizationUnits)
        {
            <li id="@organizationUnit.Id" class="jstree-open" >
                @organizationUnit.DisplayName
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```